# How to deploy add-on of google app script in Google Workspace Marketplace

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace

I am new to Google App Script. I have done coding in the google script app. I have deployed the app by the deploy option which is available in the google app script. After deployment, I am not able to find my add-on in **Google Workspace Marketplace**.
Is there any way to use an add-on without publishing it?

I have deployed the add-on with the deploy option which is available in the app script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to publish an Add-on to find it on Marketplace

- For this follow the steps as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)
- Deploying your script as an Add-on is only one of the several steps you need to follow
- Apart from this, you need to [create a project in the Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)
- [Bind your script to this project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#use_a_different_standard)
- [Set-up the OAuth screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en) for the project. Depending on either you would like to publish a privat or public Add-on - you might need to submit your [OAuth screen and the used scopes] for verification
- Then, you need to [enable and configure the Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk) in your Cloud project
- You need to deploy your script as an Add-on (this is the step you already did) and indicate the script id and deployment number within the Marketplace SDK tab `APP CONFIGURATION`
- Specify if you would like to deploy a private or public Add-on
- Complete the rest of the configuration and the [STORE LISTING](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/create-listing) tab
- If you are intending to publish a public Add-on - you need to submit it for verification and get an approval. If it's a private one (only accesible for your domain), you can publish it straightaway and will see the URL to the Marketplace listing.

As you see, the steps to publish an Add-on onGoogle Marketplace are quite laborous.

To use the Add-on without publishing it, you can use it in testing mode as described [here for Google Worskpace Addons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/create-listing) and [here for Editor Addons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons). Keep in mind that the testing mode has some [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#testing_details).

Comment: Do we need a Google Workspace Console Admin Account to upload the App to the google workspace marketplace?

Comment: @ShivYadav: Nope, you can also publish an Add-on from a free Gmail account.